# Comparison of of character type and factor type in R

Tags: r, string-matching

Ok, so I am having this issue right now. I have a matrix A whose `rownames` are the values of a field in another matrix B. I want to find indices of my `rownames` in the second matrix B. Now I am trying to do this operation `which(A$field == rowname_A)` . Unfortunately couple of things are appearing one - the `rowname_A` variable is of character class. It is of this format , `"X12345"`. The values of `A$field` is of type factor. Is there a way to remove the appended X from the character, convert it to factor and do the comparison. Or convert the factor variables of `A$field` in to character type and then do the comparison.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightfoward. The example below should help you out.

```
A <- matrix(1:3)
rownames(A) <- paste0("X", 1:3)
B <- data.frame(field = factor(1:3))

# Remove "X" from rownames(A) and check equality
B$field %in% substr(rownames(A), 2, nchar(rownames(A)))

# Add "X" to B$field and check equality
paste0("X", B$field) %in% rownames(A)
```